# Extending JavaFX Stage content with Popup(?)

Tags: javafx, popup, stage, always-on-top

It's my first post here - please be nice :)

What I'm trying to do is have controls/windows that:

1. belong to a JavaFX Stage
2. will NOT steal focus from the owning Stage when clicked
3. can be dragged beyond the boundaries of the owning Stage

I've been able to implement this in two ways; however, both are flawed. First, I've made draggable controls within the Stage's content; however, they cannot be dragged outside the Stage's area. Second, I've created them as draggable Popups anchored to the Stage; however, they remain *on top of EVERYTHING*, even when other windows are moved on top of the owning Stage.

What I'm asking is: **Is there any way to either drag a control outside the bounds of it's owning Stage; or to make a Popup NOT always appear on top of everything?**

I've found a similar question here, explaining the issue with the Popup being on top ([Javafx popup won't hide behind other application upon losing focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687370/javafx-popup-wont-hide-behind-other-application-upon-losing-focus)). But there was no acceptable solution there (I don't want the Popup to "hide" when the Stage or Application loses focus).

Thanks for reading. If you could suggest anything, it would be appreciated.

Below is an MCV example of what I tried with MoveablePopup. It works fine, except for when you bring additional windows over the top.

```
package moveablepopuptest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStroke;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStrokeStyle;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderWidths;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MoveablePopupTest extends Application
{    

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {        
        // Set up Primary Stage:
        StackPane root = new StackPane();        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);        
        primaryStage.setTitle("MoveablePopup Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        // Show a MoveablePopup for an associated node in the Stage:
        MoveablePopup popup = new MoveablePopup();
        popup.setTitle("Extension");
        Pane popupContent = new Pane();
        popupContent.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        popupContent.setMinSize(200, 200);
        popup.setContent(popupContent);
        popup.show(root, 0, 0);        

        // When Primary Stage is moved, re-anchor the popup:
        ChangeListener<Number> windowMoveListener = (ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) ->
        {
             popup.anchorToOwner();
        };       
        primaryStage.xProperty().addListener(windowMoveListener);
        primaryStage.yProperty().addListener(windowMoveListener);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    public class MoveablePopup extends Popup
    {    
        private final BorderPane bgPane = new BorderPane(); 
        private final DoubleProperty ownerXAnchorProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
        private final DoubleProperty ownerYAnchorProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);        
        private final Label titleLabel = new Label("Title");
        private Point2D lastMouse = null;      
        private Node content = null;

        public MoveablePopup()    
        {   
            // Don't want Esc to close the Popup:
            setHideOnEscape(false);

            // Create a border:
            bgPane.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.DARKORANGE, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, new BorderWidths(2))));

            // Create a title bar for the top, which will also function as a handle to move the Popup:
            StackPane barPane = new StackPane();  
            titleLabel.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
            barPane.getChildren().add(titleLabel);            
            barPane.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
            barPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.DARKORANGE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
            barPane.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, 24);
            bgPane.setTop(barPane);                         

            // Add drag/anchoring functionality to the Popup
            barPane.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) ->
            {
                lastMouse = new Point2D(event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
            });
            barPane.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) ->
            {
                double moveX = event.getScreenX() - lastMouse.getX();
                double moveY = event.getScreenY() - lastMouse.getY();
                ownerXAnchorProperty.set(ownerXAnchorProperty.doubleValue()+moveX);
                ownerYAnchorProperty.set(ownerYAnchorProperty.doubleValue()+moveY);
                lastMouse = new Point2D(event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
                anchorToOwner();
            });
            getContent().add(bgPane);        

        }

        @Override
        protected void show()
        {
            super.show();
            anchorToOwner();
        }

        public void setContent(Node content)
        {
            this.content = content;
            bgPane.setCenter(content);
        }

        public void setTitle(String title)
        {
            titleLabel.setText(title);
        }

        // Repositions the MoveablePopup so that it's relationship to
        // the owning Node's location is maintained:
        public final void anchorToOwner()
        {
            if (getOwnerNode() != null)
            {
                Point2D screenPoint = getOwnerNode().localToScreen(0, 0);
                setX(screenPoint.getX() + ownerXAnchorProperty.doubleValue());
                setY(screenPoint.getY() + ownerYAnchorProperty.doubleValue());
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: I know it may not seem like it would help, but please include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question for what you have already tried.

Comment: Alright, I added an example for the MoveablePopup approach. As far as dragging controls around on a Stage: I think that's a lot more straightforward, and the problem of not being able to drag them off the Stage a bit more clear; but I could add an example of that, too, if you wish.

Comment: No, the popup example is sufficient to help demonstrate the issue.  There is no way to achieve what you wish without creating something which subclasses Window (such as Popup), so you can't do it with a single Stage as the only Window in your application.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Seemed like I was so close except for that one annoying detail... ha. Well, thanks for the information.

Comment: "I've created them as draggable Popups anchored to the Stage; however, they remain on top of EVERYTHING, even when other windows are moved on top of the owning Stage." --> I ran your example on OS X 10.9.5, Java 8u72 and did not get this behavior.  When I move other windows on top of the owning stage, the other windows also occlude the Popup window.

Comment: That's interesting. Must be an OS thing... it most definitely happens on Windows 7. I wonder which one is the intended behavior? Granted, the popup isn't part of the owning stage's scene graph; so I would understand if it didn't automatically inherit any visibility settings. But making it immutably "alwaysOnTop" just seems... wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new stage which will be the 'popup':

```
Stage childStage = new Stage();

childStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
childStage.setTitle("Title of popup");

childStage.setScene(YOUR_SCENE);
childStage.sizeToScene();
childStage.setResizable(false);

childStage.show();
```

Comment: This is pretty much the opposite of what I want, as it explicitly prevents any events from going to the owner window's scene. What I'm looking for is a way for the parent/child to share window focus, so focus isn't switched back and forth between them.

Comment: This popup does not block the parent. This way you are still able to switch between the stages.

Maybe you require:
childStage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);

Comment: WINDOW_MODAL: (from Javadoc) "Defines a modal window that block events from being delivered to its entire owner window hierarchy."
It's possible that you meant Modality.NONE; but this is irrelevant, anyway. I was looking for a way to keep focus on the "parent" Stage.

Comment: And Modality.NONE defines a top-level window that is not modal and does not block any other window. If this is still not what you need, I think I cannot help further.

Answer (score -1):

As you have found out, everything that happens within the stage, stays within the stage (excuse the pun). So if you need some content shown outside of the stage, we can rule out everything except `Stage` itself. You can create a new stage and assign owner your initial stage. `Stage`, being a representation of a native window, will steal focus on click. However, it is possible to [request focus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#requestFocus--) back by the initial stage. That should tick your requirement boxes.

I am not sure of the use case of what you are trying to implement, but [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/) provides some extensions to existing JavaFX API, including notifications and [MDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface) windows. See if this is of any help to you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My previous version (Swing-based) used an MDI type of thing for this; but this time I wanted to avoid having to make the owning Stage larger to fit multiple internal windows inside. Also, the "request focus back" trick is something I'd like to avoid because it limits what I'm able to do inside the extension windows - they're not able to keep focus. That's one thing I liked about the Popup approach.